# Android kotlin: How to change app bar/toolbar for one fragment in an activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-toolbar

In my android app I have 4 fragments in my main activity where I can swipe left and right to access them.

Right now, each fragment has the same app bar as laid out in my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_basic_toolbar"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/white"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/bottomNavColor"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_nav_color_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_nav_color_selector"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/user_button"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/user"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/appBarLayout"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_user" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/mainNavigationFragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/main_nav_graph" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: What main activity xml looks like, each fragment is placed in the white space.]

However, I would like to change the app bar for one of the fragments (the home fragment) to have a centered logo and a taller height.

This is my MainActivity.kt where the app bar/nav controller/fragments are configured:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var user: ImageButton
    lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar
    lateinit var bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView

    lateinit var loginViewModel: LoginViewModel
    lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding: ActivityMainBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        loginViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)

        toolbar = binding.toolbar
        bottomNavigationView = binding.bottomNavigation
        user = binding.userButton

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

        Fresco.initialize(this)

        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.mainNavigationFragment) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController
        bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)

        // Set up tool bar with navController and appBarConfiguration
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.homeFragment,
                R.id.mapFragment,
                R.id.resourcesFragment,
                R.id.moreFragment
            )
        )
        toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

        // Show navigation bar and user bottom on top level fragments
        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            when (destination.id) {
                R.id.homeFragment,
                R.id.mapFragment,
                R.id.resourcesFragment,
                R.id.moreFragment -> {
                    bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    user.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
                else -> {
                    bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.GONE
                    user.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            }
        }

        user.setOnClickListener {
            loginViewModel.loadAccount(this@MainActivity, binding.root) {
                navController.navigate(R.id.userFragment)
            }

        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            user.callOnClick()
        }
    }

}
```

What I have tried so far:

In my HomeFragment.kt onCreateView, where I would like to change the app bar/toolbar, I added the following line of code:

```
        (activity as MainActivity?)!!.supportActionBar!!.setLogo(R.drawable.logo_mt)
```

This successfully placed my logo in the center, but it changed every fragments app bar and not just the home fragment. I would also like to be able to edit the logos size and the toolbars size.

Answer (score 2):

The typical recommendation is to remove the toolbar from the `Activity`, and add one in each `Fragment`'s layout instead. That way you can configure each one however you like (even if most of them are identical). If you're doing a single-activity app, you might run into a "I don't always need a toolbar" situation, and if it's a shared activity, it can't have things that aren't shared across all components.

Just bear in mind if you go this way, the `setUpWithNavController` call sets the title on your toolbar using any `label` values set on destinations in your nav graph. And when you navigate to another fragment, that title may change to the new destination a split second before the fragment changes. Not a problem if the destination has a toolbar and the title is in the same place - but you might see a glitch if one is centred, because it'll be obvious if the title changes early

---

Another thing you could try (haven't done it myself but it's an idea) is having the activity manage the toolbar - height, centering etc. When a fragment attaches, it could inform the activity what it needs the toolbar to look like. You could just have an interface on the parent activity, or have a `ViewModel` with some `ToolbarConfig` value that it observes, and that the fragment sets, that kind of thing. Might want to look into using a `CoordinatorLayout` to make it grow and shrink all fancy-like

Comment: Did you find a solution to this flickering issue?

Answer (score 1):

Set theme to `NoActionBar` and then set custom `toolbar` in `AppBarLayout` in each fragment as per your need

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could you expand on this a little bit with actual code?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did with a seamless slide between fragments. I can put any button on any toolbar and resize them. You can see both toolbars simultaneously as it slides back and forth and easily respond to the movements. I should sign up for Git to post a sample as it would probably be easier to see it in action.

This button:

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/btnDroid"
android:layout_width="24dp"
android:layout_height="24dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="46dp"
android:background="@drawable/ic_bot"
android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
android:elevation="4dp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/appBarLayout"
tools:ignore="DuplicateSpeakableTextCheck,TouchTargetSizeCheck" />
```

is on what looks like the Activity main toolbar but it's not. The TouchTargetSizeCheck is not material as the buttons turn out at 48x48. This button is in the first fragment file called fragment_first.xml that runs a constraint layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

And the toolbar can easily resize and have any text title:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/teal_700"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
            app:title="@string/app_name"/>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

I think I am going to implement this for future apps because I can't find official documentation otherwise.

Comment: @helvete My answer is clearer now. I'm still working on getting a repository for this app.